# Content of static cells in TableViewController not displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm programming with XCode just for a few weeks, so I'm not a pro. But now I'm having a problem which I think is very basic but I can't solve it. I've created a new project with an UITableViewController with static cells and filled them with UILabels. I also created a MainTableView.h and a MainTableView.m. In the .m file I'v deleted the three functions (numberOfRowsInSection, numberOfSections? and cellForRowAtIndexPath), just as it's shown in many tutorials. Although it's not working. If I build and start it, the tables are correctly shown but not their content(the labels). What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please show us your code, we can't help with the current amount of information you've provided.

Comment: You should change from sttic to dynamic cell types

Comment: I think u didn't add DataSource and Delegate to your UITableViewController.

Answer (score 2):

Please check color of UILable , And check if have set UIUITableViewdeleagte and UIUITableViewdatasourse for UITableView